# C# WinForm text change/ exit prompt

Tags: c#, text, editor

Just out of being bored, I decided to start building my own text editor. I have been having trouble with my coding, so my teacher had suggested building smaller programs that I wanted to write to help get me more familiar with the language, and since I couldn't think of anything, I ended up making this text editor.

I've been trying to root through the code on my own as much as possible, but I was wondering how to make the text that appears at the top of the form (beside the icon) reflect the current filename (or "new" or something if there is no file loaded) as well as having the * if the file has been edited.

I would also like to know how to code my exit button to check if the text has been edited before closing, and ask the user to save if it has, as well as having this show up if the user uses the "X" button in the corner, which currently flat out exits the program no matter what.

Answer (score 1):

To change the title (text besides the icon):

```
Form1.Text = "This is a new title";
```

where `Form1` is the name of you form object

To check if text is saved:
Hold a boolean variable that indicates whether the user saved the text or not.
Use the `Form_Closing` method to check if this variable is set to true, and do as you wish
More on Form_Closing [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.closing.aspx)

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. Where exactly would I put in the "Form1.Text.." because when I try adding it in anywhere in my code, it does not give me the "Text" option.

And I have a Form_Load method, but no Form_Closing method. Do I add the Form_Closing method in, and just mirror how the Form_Load one looks? I'm still pretty new to programming in general

Comment: @MattMiller Use the Form1_Load method with 'this.Text = ...' instead.
As for the Form_Closing - you have to generate the method stub yourself OR use the Properties window in VS (while choosing the properties of your main form) to create the Form_Closing method stub

Comment: Thank you. I took that and put it into the Open button code, and I got my desired effect; I was even able to cut out a label that I had that I didn't really want by just declaring a string variable before an if statement that now assigns the current filename value to the string. As for the Form_Closing, it will take some playing around to get it right, I'm sure. I tried following the instructions in the msdn link, but nothing came up when I clicked the "X" so I'll keep working at it. I've only been working with C# since september, and my "teaching" has been whatever I've taught myself.

Comment: @MattMiller It's easy: on the Design window, Right click on your form - and then choose Properties - the properties window will appear to your right (by default?) - you can then navigate to the Events window (a tiny 'lightning' icon) - In there, you can double click the FormClosing event in order to generate the method.

Comment: That I had figured out. I meant that working out the code on the inside was going to take awhile. Basically, I want to check to see if my multiline text box has been changed since the last save, and if yes, inform the user in a sort of "global exit check" kind of thing, with a message box with yes/no options, Yes referring it to the savebutton method, no being close.

Comment: You can use the KeyPress event for your TextBox to indicate whether the user changed it's content or not.

Answer (score 1):

Many questions :)

Let me answer a few of them:

1. In your own code, you should probably set a "dirty bit".  In other words, declare a boolean variable that says whether or not the text changed.  "Changed" is something you, the programmer, needs to define.  It can mean many different things - you get to decide.
2. Each Winform "control" has a set of "properties", most of which you can change programmatically (on-the-fly).  Your "form" has a "text" property that changes the title.  Label, Button and other controls also have their own "text" property you can change at will.
3. Each Winform control also has a set of "events" you can override.  The "Close" event is the easiest way to manage program shutdown - including if somebody pressed the "X" button.  This is also a good place to check your "dirty bit", and save the file accordingly.